# Optionally display iframe in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, repeater

I have a repeater with several items. I have an optional embedded Youtube video that I only want to display if there is a url in the `src` attribute.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Heading") %></h3>
                <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Content") %> </p>
                <iframe id="Video" width="640" height="360" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoUrl") %>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this one with the line that you have iframe in it:

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoUrl") != null) ? 
        "<iframe id='Video' width='640' height='360' src='" + 
         DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoUrl") + 
        "' allowfullscreen></iframe>" : "" %>
```